# how to created a curved background on top of image

Tags: html, css

I have this design 
[image]

How can I make the blue curved background on top of the image (**I need the transparency as well**) ?

I started it with a different backgournd but I don't know where to go from there. Any help will be really appreciated.

```css
.bg {
  background-image:url("https://s8.postimg.cc/rsxes8dx1/red_or_blue_pill_crimson_quill-12.jpg");
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.bluebg {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="bluebg">

  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0rsLxtw5/7/

Comment: It looks like just a static image to me. How do you want it to work when the browser window is resized?

Comment: @Dai I want it to stay the same so the blue area covers about 75% of the image no mater the size of the image itself.

Comment: But the image has a fixed size, so what should happen when the browser is resized to `200x20000px` compared to `200x200px`?

Comment: @Dai I don't know if I understood your quesiton properly but I want the height to be fixed but the width stretches. So when the width is 20 000px then I want 75% of it in blue with the curve and the other area in white. I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the below-given snippet helps!

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url("https://s8.postimg.cc/rsxes8dx1/red_or_blue_pill_crimson_quill-12.jpg");
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bluebg {
  background: rgba(135, 206, 235, 0.5);
  height: 140%;
  width: 90%;
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at right, transparent 0, transparent 30%, black 30px);
  mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at right, transparent 0, transparent 30%, black 30px);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="bluebg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

I changed your HTML like the parent as child and child as parent.

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url("https://s8.postimg.cc/rsxes8dx1/red_or_blue_pill_crimson_quill-12.jpg");
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at 98% 50%);
  clip-path: circle(50% at 98% 50%);
}

.bluebg {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bluebg">
  <div class="bg">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the background is not transparent. I tried to add `opacity` but it didn't work. How can I have it as the image above ? The curve looks great though. Thanks again

Comment: I am really sorry brother. I have never seen something like you expected. There may be solutions exist. But I have no idea. You need to be tricky in this case.If you want to have `opacity` layer I don't think that we can do it with the current HTML DOM. wait for someone else's answer. I usually add a transparent png img as a layer and using `position:absolute`, I take the png img over the image. I never used to create it with css. Wait for somone else's answer. If my answer seems helpful make a upvote on it.Thank you

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort and explanation. I will wait for it and if no one answers then I will choose this as best answer as it gave me some insights of how to do it by using another transparent image. So thanks again and I up voted the answer.

Comment: Happy to help ;-)